# Uncle Elroy's bedroom scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, next-friday

There's a specific scene in the movie in which the main character Craig gets a tax notice from the mailman at the door of his Uncle's house. He goes upstairs to his Uncle's room to give him the mail but after two attempts get grabbed into a bed with his Uncle and Aunt trying to escape whatever is happening at the moment. What happened? I never really understood this scene in the movie. I have a link to a video of the clip that I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Craig's aunt and uncle are shown to be into some kinky stuff, based on what Craig sees in the room, the sex toys, the projector playing what looks like porn, and the way his aunt acts throughout the movie. They probably (probably as in I have no director or actor source) grabbed him in the continuation of some role-playing sex-game they were doing before they fell asleep, not realizing it was their nephew they were grabbing.

To back this sup a bit, here are a few lines from [the script](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/n/next-friday-script-transcript-cube.html):

```
      Craig: Unc, you got this tax notice, man.

      Elroy: Come here! I'll tear that ass up again! (Elroy implying this is not the first time he has done this)

      Suga: I like it when you treat me rough! (Suga acknowledging this as familiar treatment)
```